# How to setup complete file access and control on a network

Tags: windows, samba

I have a media server running ubuntu 12.04 and I want it setup so that any PC on the network (windows etc) has complete access to all files, folders etc with read, write, edit, copy to, copy from permissions.

No need for security (IE no password or user name, just select it on the network and start editing). I have samba installed and personal file sharing is enabled but my windows PC cannot see it on the network.

I already set up another server as I described but unfortunately I can't remember how or where I found the guides for it.

Any one know of a guide that covers what I want?

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for permission change wouldn't you cd to the directory of the share and use: sudo chmod -R 777 /home/"user"/"folder"